# Why does my migrations not run when deploying Laravel app to Render.com?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, render.com

I am trying to migrate an existing Laravel app of mine to Render.com (from Heroku); I have followed the Render.com [tutorial on how to do this](https://render.com/docs/deploy-php-laravel-docker).

I have created the appropriate Dockerfile and 00-laravel-deploy.sh files as requested and they look like this.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:2.1.2

COPY . .

# Image config
ENV SKIP_COMPOSER 1
ENV WEBROOT /var/www/html/public
ENV PHP_ERRORS_STDERR 1
ENV RUN_SCRIPTS 1
ENV REAL_IP_HEADER 1

# Laravel config
ENV APP_ENV production
ENV APP_DEBUG false
ENV LOG_CHANNEL stderr

# Allow composer to run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

I have updated the fpm image to one that works with my composer packages, as I need PHP 8.1.

**00-laravel-deploy.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Running composer"
#composer global require hirak/prestissimo
composer install --no-dev --working-dir=/var/www/html

echo "Caching config..."
php artisan config:cache

echo "Caching routes..."
php artisan route:cache

echo "Running migrations..."
php artisan migrate --force
```

Pay attention to the last command, there is a command to run my migrations. Now when Render.com attempts to build my web-service, the website simply returns a 500 error.

The error logs indicate the tables are missing, but no where does it state the migrations have run. Weirdly I can see when caching the routes, the database errors occurs.

[You can see the error log here](https://pastebin.com/HPyRnuJg), I cannot post here because it is too long.

Can anyone suggest how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `AppServiceProvider` is making a database query on line 45. This blows up because the tables don't exist. This is being run as part of the Composer dump-autoload process which runs after your Composer install, so it fails before it gets to the migration step.

Comment: also, caching config and routes prior to running the migration is not recommended/good as for caching routes it need to query to DB.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. Your routes shouldn't need to query the database.

Comment: How would you suggest I can fix this? How can I run the migrations before anything else is run? @Dwight

Comment: You can't, the `AppServiceProvider` will run as part of booting the app. The app needs to be booted before the migrations are run. If you share what you're doing in `AppServiceProvider` we could perhaps offer alternative solutions but realistically you shouldn't have a query running like that.